# Inserting Multiple values into MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I'm wondering how to insert multiple values into a database.

Below is my idea, however nothing is being added to the database.

I return the variables above (email, serial, title) successfully. And i also connect to the database successfully.

The values just don't add to the database.

I get the values from an iOS device and send _POST them.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

After i get the values by using the above code. I use echo to ensure they have values.

Now I try to add them to the database:

```
  //Query Check
        $assessorEmail = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT ace_id,email_address FROM assessorID WHERE email_address = '$email'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($assessorEmail) == 0) {

            echo " Its go time add it to the databse.";

            //It is unqiue so add it to the database
            mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO assessorID (email_address, serial_code, title)
            VALUES ('$email','$serial','$title')");

        } else {

            die(UnregisteredAssessor . ". Already Exists");

        }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: @Mihai I'm counting 3, I've only been doing this for a day so if I'm still incorrect...

Comment: My bad, check if the values are set you might have a NOT NULL column.

Comment: Which message are you getting? "Its go time add it to the databse."? Or "Already Exists"?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using mysqli, I'd instead do a prepared statement

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "INSERT INTO assessorID (email_adress, serial_code, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $email, $serial, $title);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

This is of course using procedural style as you did above. This will ensure it's a safe entry you're making as well.